# CORS Policy in ASP .net core3.1

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I have the following API code in .net core

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
..............
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                                    builder => builder
                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .WithOrigins("https://domain.com.xx")
                                    .AllowCredentials()
                                 );
            });

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(x=>x.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
}
```

and my Configure method as

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I am getting an **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apiservername/api/mycall' from origin 'https:domain.com.xx' has been clocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

The client is in Angular 7 and the method I am calling is POST method. I have it always working with http. On the client side on the interceptor I am adding

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
............
....
    url: request.url.replace('http://','https://')
}
```

wondering if I am missing anything here. Both Client site (In angular) and API side (.NET Core ASP 3.1) are set up as https. 
---edited--
I enabled the exception handling and after that I got the below error from the eventviewer.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Does this means the issue is with authentication of token? I am using Azure AD for authenticating the login and then validating that for using the asp .net core WebAPIs.

Comment: In configure method, Can you move app.UseCors("CorsPolicy") code above app.UseAuthentication()?

Comment: I pushed it up , but the result is same. I can see the pack with details in Fiddler, still I get the same issue

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Is it working fine with '.AllowAnyOrigin()'

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60091440/cors-error-keep-happening-even-after-enabling-it-with-net-core-and-angular-cli

Comment: Hi Bob, my cors was not in the order specified by this thread, and I rearranged it as mentioned , but still of no use. It says `"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:<MyapiCall> from origin <myClientURI>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Hi @sideshowbarker after putting `app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    var exception = errorFeature.Error;
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                });
            });` I got a 500 server error response in the devtools panel of Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Sorry should have posted/followed up sometime ago. The issue was the **firewall** it should be opened up. I advised the infra team to let me in and like to ack the information in the link [UnblockFirewall](https://www.stephenwagner.com/2018/01/21/azure-ad-connect-blocked-firewall/) helped us. Finally it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it work for you. Just ignore the MVC part I just want to point the order because the pipeline order is matter

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddCors();
      services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Mine is an Endpoint so no MVC, but still giving the same issue as Access-Control-Allow-origin' header is present on the requested source

Comment: when I give everything as localhost it works.. my client origin is `https:localhost:<port>` and there is no issue and I am running it locally. Only when I change it to `https:<servername.com.xx>` it raises the CORS issue and that too on the Server. Will the SSL certificates or the way SSL is configured make any difference?

Comment: Yes I think so it may be the problem come from your hosting service which hositing service you are using ?

Comment: Hi Tony.. This is internal application and hosted internally using reverse proxy we are giving access to select customers. It's an in house application.

Comment: I think the problem come from proxy

Answer (score -1):

Try with this instead .WithOrigins("domain.com.xx")

Comment: Hi Duy, I changed, but unfortunately the result is the same.. it's blocked